# Windows Powershell Output to File. Strange Characters

Tags: windows, powershell, echo

Running this command:

```
echo "foo" > test.txt
```

I get strange results in test.txt. I actually can't even copy-paste the contents directly here in stack overflow but need to show the hex output of the file. Which looks like this-

```
ff fe 66 00 6f 00 6f 00 0d 00 0a 00
```

Not sure what `FF` and `FE` are but it looks like it's also placing `NULL` between each character.

Can any Windows people guide me in the right direction as to why this is happening and how I can resolve it? I just want to the contents "foo" to be placed in that file unmolested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0xFFFE` is the [Unicode byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-16 LE (little endian), which is normal Windows Unicode.

The contents of your file are the two byte BOM, 0x6600 ("f"), 0x6f00 ("o"), 0x6f00 ("o"), 0x0d00 ("`r" or carriage return), 0x0a00 ("`n" or new line)

Try:

```
echo "foo" | Out-File -FilePath test.txt -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: Ah I see. So those aren't nulls, they are just the extra length given it's 16bit encoded. Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  You can kind of confirm what's going on like this:  `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([byte[]](0xff,0xfe,0x66,0x00,0x6f,0x00,0x6f,0x00,0x0d,0x00,0x0a,0x00))`.

Comment: Could also use `Set-Content` which uses ASCII/ANSI/whatever as default.